# Problem related to anaconda and python libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Every time I import any library in jupyter shows this type of error ,I'm using 64 bit window os.

```
OSError Traceback (most recent call last) in ----> 1 import pandas as pd 2 digit = pd.read_csv(r'E:\ML_Codes\all\train.csv')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas__init__.py in 9 for dependency in hard_dependencies: 10 try: ---> 11 import(dependency) 12 except ImportError as e: 13 missing_dependencies.append(f"{dependency}: {e}")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python3.7\site-packages\numpy__init__.py in 138 139 # Allow distributors to run custom init code --> 140 from . import _distributor_init 141 142 from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy_distributor_init.py in 24 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL 25 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction? ---> 26 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename)) 27 DLL_filenames.append(filename) 28 if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

C:\anacondanewww\lib\ctypes__init__.py in init(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error) 362 363 if handle is None: --> 364 self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) 365 else: 366 self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the error messages,there seems to be some kind of dependency issue which is resulting from some weird installation error I believe.

For the easiest solution,what I would suggest is to remove all instances of Python3.x and delete the folders(Do the same for the anaconda installation) and then reinstall anaconda and then try

The second thing that could be wrong is that while running the Jupyter notebook,you are maybe not using the correct python version which has the pandas library installed.See if you get multiple options to choose in the upper right hand side where it mentions the Python version that you need to choose.